# merging 5 million files efficiently

Tags: bash, tail, merge

Due to some poor planning i have a directory containing > 5 million files totalling roughly 20GB.
Each file contains 32 lines of garbage at the top followed by an unknown number of lines of important data.

I want to merge all important data into a single file.

I was doing this:

```
for i in $(find); do tail -n +32 $i >> ../all.txt; done
```

all.txt was only growing about .5MB a second. Is there a faster way to accomplish this? Also, eliminating the files as I go would be handy as I'm likely to run out of disk space before completing the job :X

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `tail -n +32` actually skips **31** lines, and _retains_ line 32 in 1-origin numbering

Comment: Before going through did you ask yourself who & how often this main 20Gb will be opened/closed ? and consequences of that ?  *Also, you will allways be limited in performance by openning/closing (individual file) & writing result on main huge one by the disk buffer size, speed & ram/bus speed of course.*

Answer (score 2):

If deleting the files as you go is required, then something along what you wrote is already a fast way of doing it.  One optimization is, instead of using `find` to list the file contents, you can use `*`, which lists the files as they are listed in the directory listing, without incurring additional processing time from `find`.  Namely, you would write:

```
for i in *; do tail -n +3 $i >> ../x; rm $i; done
```

However, if you can spare deleting them until you're done merging them, and if you also wish to keep, which content came from which file, there is a way to parse them to tail many at a time (as many as your shell allows).  The command for this would be:

```
find . -exec tail -n +3 {} >> ../x +
```

The `+` at the end would tell `find` to pass filenames many at a time, instead of one at a time.  This would result in tremendous performance increase (due to the much smaller number of instances of `tail` called), but your output file would still have something along the lines of

```
==> ./filename <==
```

printed every time one file ended and the next began.  Also, the files would not be deleted as you go.

If you would like to remove the line above at the cost of a little bit of speed, you can run it via

```
find . -exec awk 'FNR>32' {} +
```

(thanks dave_thompson for the suggestion as a comment).

Finally, if you would prefer the output that lists which information came from which file, and would still like to delete them as you go, you can use iruvar's answer to do this, with both `\;`'s replaced by `+`'s (my original answer only described what to do; iruvar gave the actual command for it).

Comment: To do a group at a time without the `==> file <==` headings `-exec awk 'FNR>32' {} +`

Comment: If you are working with GNU `tail` you may suppress the filename headers using the `-q/--quiet` option. `tail` will typically blow `awk` out of the water in its niche so it worth sticking with it

Comment: @iruvar I know it's faster, that's why I said that `at the cost of a little bit of speed`.  "little bit" being because it's still much faster than running `tail` on one file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is likely IO-bound so optimizing the loop will yield marginal improvements at best. If you are OK with operating on files depth-first, you could roll the `tail` and `rm` invocations into `find`, deleting as you go along

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec tail -n +32 {} \; -delete >../all.txt
```

Ideally we'd like to be able to get `find` to pass multiple files to `tail` at once by replacing `\;` with `+` but I can't seem to get that to work in conjunction with `-delete`

With a `find` that lacks the `-delete` option

```
find . -type f -exec tail -n +32 {} \; -exec rm {} \; >../all.txt
```

or on a GNU system that allows the passing of `-q` to `tail` for suppressing the printing of file headers when `tail` receives multiple files:

```
find . -type f -exec tail -q -n +32 {} + -exec rm {} + >../all.txt
```

Note - with `-exec rm`, the depth-first search as applicable to `-delete` no longer applies
This last incantation is likely to turn out to be the most performant of it all